# Apply utility method to externalizing text - Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I can't apply utility method to externalizing text, this is my code:

```
th:text="${#strings.escapeXml(config.companyname)}"
```

What is the error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I answer:

```
th:utext="${#strings.escapeXml(#messages.msg('config.companyname'))}"
```